# Can't access apache after changing ports to non-80

Tags: configuration, virtualhost, apache

I don't know what's wrong, I just changed /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf and now I can't access it from non-loopback address.

After the change:

```
Listen 2999
<VirtualHost *:*>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html"
</VirtualHost>
```

Output of `lsof -i:2999`

```
COMMAND   PID   USER   FD   TYPE   DEVICE SIZE NODE NAME
httpd   23989   root    4u  IPv4 27581116       TCP *:remoteware-un (LISTEN)
httpd   24001 apache    4u  IPv4 27581116       TCP *:remoteware-un (LISTEN)
httpd   24002 apache    4u  IPv4 27581116       TCP *:remoteware-un (LISTEN)
httpd   24003 apache    4u  IPv4 27581116       TCP *:remoteware-un (LISTEN)
httpd   24004 apache    4u  IPv4 27581116       TCP *:remoteware-un (LISTEN)
httpd   24005 apache    4u  IPv4 27581116       TCP *:remoteware-un (LISTEN)
httpd   24006 apache    4u  IPv4 27581116       TCP *:remoteware-un (LISTEN)
httpd   24007 apache    4u  IPv4 27581116       TCP *:remoteware-un (LISTEN)
httpd   24008 apache    4u  IPv4 27581116       TCP *:remoteware-un (LISTEN)
```

I can access apache using `nc localhost 2999` or `w3m http://localhost:2999`
But I can't access 2999 port using my ip or dns. I can access other ports using my ip or DNS.

I don't have an idea what's wrong. Iptables isn't blocking that port.

EDIT: Okay, iptables was actually blocking that port. I tried `service stop iptables` and I could access it.

Comment: System administration questions belong on http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: Tried wireshark or tcpdump yet to see what might be going on?

Comment: Nope, I can't see what is going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using an external router you should forward the new port to the server.

If you are not using an external router then be sure that you don't have iptables configured to only accept connections from localhost.

Comment: But I can access other ports I created. Its just httpd that doesn't work